# How to configure Varnish in Magento 2 admin?

Tags: magento2, admin, varnish

I've my Magento 2 installed in Cloudways with Varnish enabled, I'm sure that Varnish is well configured because it works in other projects and I can't change the configuration, I'm using the default Magento configuration with Varnish enabled.

[image: Magento 2 Varnish admin configuration]

am I using the configuration right?

Answer (score 0):

I had to configure the server IP, the NGINX port is the same as the default 8080.

[image: Magento 2 Varnish admin configuration]